# Change bound function parameters

Tags: javascript, function, binding, partial, currying

Given a simple function:

```
const a = (x) => (y) => x + y
```

and its partially applied version:

```
const b = a(3)
```

Is there any way to change the already bound parameter in `b`? Something like

```
b.boundArgs[0] = 5
```

So that if I call `b(5)` it would return `10` and not `8`

---

***A bit of background:***

*I use a library which returns partially applied function as a result from one of the library functions calls.

I have to modify the first argument (that is applied by the library function) and I don't want to copy-paste the implementation of this function. I'd like to stay with the library as is except for this small modification.*

Comment: No, there is no way to do that in your example.

Comment: And where is the initial function called? You have to modify that

Comment: @JonasW. The initial function is called in the library, so I can't modify that

Comment: Then its impossible :/

Comment: @Pointy this means the only way to do that is duplicating the library implementation and modifying that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that unless the library in question makes it possible to do that. Which it could, but probably doesn't.

Basically what you're asking is if you can reach into the execution context a function closes over and change variable values (more accurately, *bindings*) in that context. You can't by default. Using a more verbose example:

```
const a = (x) => {
    const b = (y) => x + y;
    return b;
};
```

There's nothing you can do by default with `b` that lets you reach in and change the `x` in the environment `b` closes over.

Earlier I said the library could let you do that, but probably doesn't. Here's one way it could do that:

```js
const a = (x) => {
    const b = (y) => x + y;
    b.changeX = (newX) => {
        x = newX;
    };
    return b;
};
const b = a(3);
b.changeX(10);
console.log(b(5)); // 15 instead of 8
```

You still can't find out what `x` is bound to `b`, but you can change it through `changeX`.

Or the libray could just use a property on the function it returns:

```js
const a = (x) => {
    const b = (y) => b.x + y; // Note b.x
    b.x = x;                  // Initial value
    return b;
};
const b = a(3);
b.x = 10;
console.log(b(5)); // 15 instead of 8
```

I'm not suggesting in any way that this is a good idea, encapsulation usually serves an important purpose. Just pointing out that it's possible to do this sort of thing.